# Using JaCoCo to get project-wide coverage

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a project with two modules, one containing the code (`submodule1`), and the other containing the unit tests(`submodule2`). Running coverage tests on `submodule1` provides coverage results of 0%, since the methods are supposed to be tested in `submodule2`. Running coverage tests on `submodule2` however only returns coverage for classes defined in that module.

I have been trying to create a project-wide coverage and I've found the following:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java'
    ]

    jacocoTestReport {
        additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
        sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
        classDirectories =  files(sourceSets.main.output)
        reports {
            html.enabled = true
            xml.enabled = true
            csv.enabled = false
        }
    }

    test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.jacocoTestReport)
}

task jacocoRootReport(type: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport) {
    additionalSourceDirs = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.output)

    dependsOn = subprojects.test

    executionData = files(subprojects.jacocoTestReport.executionData)

    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
    }

    onlyIf = {
        true
    }

    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
            it.exists()
        })
    }
}
```

However I'm unable to run it, since I get this error when trying to run `./gradlew jacocoRootReport`:

```
Could not find method jacocoTestReport() for arguments [build_6nnhcgikryugeat1c382yp5m6$_run_closure3$_closure6@1a3e8e24] on root project 'MyProject'.
```

How can I fix this?